# Scripting and dynamic loading in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, reflection, scripting

I'm mostly posting here to look for information. 
I have a large scale automation written in VB.net. I would like to allow my customers to write and execute their own scripts in my framework.

Does VB.net have some kind of script extension, where my customer could write code that references my code (not currently located in a library but I suppose it could be.)

So for example, I want them to write a test script.
I then want my software to run this script and display the results in my GUI.

I know there are many ways of approaching this, reflection etc.. I'm just appealing to those with more .Net knowledge than myself for the "right" approach.

In addition to his problem, I have some code that is basically drivers for equipment. The issue is, this code needs to change based on the version of the controlled device's software.

What is a good approach to loading these in dynamically? Currently the are objects that implement an abstract class. Can I create a mapping between final code and the abstract object? What approach would be best here?

Comment: You can use for instance [**CodeDom**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12852/Compile-and-Run-VB-NET-Code-using-the-CodeDom) to compile code in memory.

Comment: Can you load in your own reference (aka reference the other code in the project) without putting it all into dll's.

Comment: Don't know, I'm afraid. Without DLLs I would guess _not_, but I am not sure.